# asp.net WebRequest stream throwing 'This stream does not support seek operations' error in debugger

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, webrequest

Im new to WebRequest calls in asp.net.   I'm trying to use WebRequest with the Expedia (EAN) API (https://developer.ean.com/code-library/).   They have an example that doesn't work (as far as I can tell) and do not help coders even with their own API.

Here are my issues:

When I make the request.GetRequestStream() call in the debugger I get back a
"   '((System.Net.ConnectStream)dataStream).Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'" with the value "This stream does not support seek operations".

Of course then the GetResponse() call times out.

I am also NOT clear on which part of the web string gets sent to the .Create method (xmlpath below) and which part gets streamed to the request (postData below)??

Here is the code:

```
string xmlpath = "http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/avail?";
string postData = "minorRev=99&cid=55505&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&_type=json&hotelId=125719&arrivalDate=11/11/2015&departureDate=11/13/2015&includeDetails=true&includeRoomImages=true&room1=2,5,7";

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(xmlpath);
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
request.Timeout = 10000;

Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();

WebResponse myResponse = request.GetResponse();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream());
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

I know this might be a lot considering its a 3rd party API, but does anyone see what I might be doing wrong???

Thanks,
-Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check their documentation you will see:

> Services within the EAN API are accessed via this standard base URL
>   format for all protocols

Which means that you need to do a GET request and paste search parameters in URL. So your code might look like that:

```
var url =
    "http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/avail" +
    "?minorRev=99&cid=55505&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_US" +
    "&currencyCode=USD&_type=json&hotelId=125719&arrivalDate=11/11/2015" +
    "&departureDate=11/13/2015&includeDetails=true" +
    "&includeRoomImages=true&room1=2,5,7";
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "GET";

using (var res = req.GetResponse())
{
    using (var resStream = res.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(resStream))
        {
            var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

And you really don't need to mess with all these requests, responses and streams. If you are using .Net 4.5 then take a look at [HttClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). With this class code will be very short:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var json = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Aleksandr... Appreciate the answer as they both work perfectly for me.  Especially enjoy how easy it is in 4.5.

Thanks again!